# When pyqt5 program executed, Don't show window

Tags: python, pyqt5

After rename program, this problem happened but i have tried another examples but still dont show window

```
import PyQt5.QtWidgets as qtw
import PyQt5.QtGui as qtg

class MainWindow(qtw.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        # add atitle
        self.setWindowTitle("My First GUI Program")

        #set vertical layout
        self.setLayout(qtw.QVBoxLayout())

        # Create a label
        my_label = qtw.QLabel("Hello World! What's your name ?")

        # change the font siz of label
        my_label.setFont(qtg.QFont("Helvetica", 18))
        self.layout().addWidget(my_label)

        # Create entry box
        my_entry_box = qtw.QLineEdit()
        my_entry_box.setObjectName("name_field")
        my_entry_box.setText("")
        self.layout().addWidget(my_entry_box)

        # Create a button
        my_button = qtw.QPushButton("Press Me!", clicked = lambda: press_it())
        self.layout().addWidget(my_button)

        # Show the app
        self.show()

        def press_it():
            # add name to label
            my_label.setText(f'Hello {my_entry_box.text()}!')
            
            # Clear the entry box
            my_entry_box.setText("")

app =qtw.QApplication([])
mw = MainWindow()

# Run The App
app.exec_()
```

Comment: Your question is unclear, could you explain me better

Comment: Your code is working absolutely fine on my end.

Comment: Are you running your application in some special environment?

Comment: @MehmetBAYRAKCI If you are on windows then the extension of your script must be .pyw so I recommend you change the .py to that extension. It would also be recommended that you open a CMD and run: `python /path/of/script.py`. Please use  `@username`

Comment: @MehmetBAYRAKCI Have you run the script from the CMD?

Comment: @MehmetBAYRAKCI Do you get any error messages? We need feedback. If you get nothing then run `QT_DEGUG_PLUGINS=1 python /path/of/script.py`

Comment: @eyllanesc i have tried everything. Delete VSC IDE and Python and reinstall tehm. But my problem is going on. I can not see what i did in code. Please help me. Also I tried to code with using tkinter pack. Its working. But Pyqt5 doesn't.

Comment: 1) Duplicate occurs in 2 ways: When there is a similar question with an answer that the user thinks solves the problem OR when a user posts an identical question in multiple posts, I mark it as a duplicate using the second approach. 2) That you publish several posts with the same content you will not get anything good, only that your post is closed, probably DV and also annoying the community. 3) In SO we are a small community (and in PyQt even more) so probably the 26 users who review your post are already all of us who respond so new posts will not attract more people.

Comment: [cont.] 4) You still haven't given me feedback on my last comment

Comment: what is the name of the file?